# How do I get rid of unnecessary space between buttons in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a series of buttons across the top of the page. These buttons act as links and droplists. There is space occurring between the buttons that I can't get rid of. Is there a way to get rid of this space?

Also, the first button is a link. The others are not yet setup, except for the ones that are droplists. Anyway, when I had the html code as follows, if you weren't exactly on top of the link, the entire box became the same color as the page background, effectively creating a blank.

```
<BUTTON class="dropbtn"><A href="index.html">Wolf3DMall</A></BUTTON>
```

Swapping the BUTTON and A tags fixed that problem:

```
<A href="index.html"><BUTTON class="dropbtn">Wolf3DMall</BUTTON></A>
```

But the validator complained in both cases about it not being valid HTML. You can't have a BUTTON as a child of an Anchor, and you can't have an Anchor as a child of a BUTTON. So, even though this works in both Firefox and Edge (IE doesn't recognize the link), is there a valid way to do this without having to resort to a FORM?

[Here](https://wayneca.neocities.org/Wolfenstein/wolf3dMall.html) is the link to the page.

**Edit**: Well, Juan, the HTML code I used to achieve the link/button combo is here in this post already. I'm asking for an alternative that is valid HTML.

As to the code, you obviously didn't look at the page or you would know why I want a link/button combo by the way the page looks and the way the buttons operate. You would also see the space problem I am speaking of.

There isn't that much CSS in the page that someone would feel like they were "digging through a bunch of code" to find something. However, since this code is based on an example on the W3Schools site, here is a link to the [Try It](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) part of the example I used. To recreate the effect of the space between the buttons, all you have to do is scroll to the bottom of the listing and copy the html code for the button (both divs) and paste it below the first one, then run the code. You will have your example with the least amount of code possible.

**Edit2**: Thanks to everyone who responded. The problems are now corrected. For the link problem, all I had to do was place the class I had on the button on the anchor instead, and remove the button:

```
<DIV class="dropdown"><A class="dropbtn" href="index.html">Wolf3DMall</A></DIV>
```

Adding the display:flex to the div as indicated fixed the space problem. You guys rock!

Comment: Why do you think you want a link within a button or a button within a link? A link should look like a link and a form submit button should look like a button. Where is the CSS? A link to an external site is not recommended, most people are not willing to dig through a whole bunch of code to figure out what you're asking. You should create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example showing the HTML and the CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to change anything. You just need to add `display: flex` to the parent `div` of the menu to remove the unnecessary `space` between buttons in the menu.

**Live Demo:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #103872;
  color: lightseagreen;
  front-family: verdana;
}

a:link {
  color: #103872;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #103872;
}

a:hover {
  color: lightseagreen;
}

a:active {
  color: #103872;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  color: #103872;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 0;
  font: bold 11px verdana;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  font: bold 11px verdana;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: forestgreen;
  padding: 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #103872;
  color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:auto;width:95%;display: flex;">
  <div class="dropdown"><a href="index.html"><button class="dropbtn">Wolf3DMall</button></a></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Original PC</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Wolf.htm">Wolfenstein 3D</a>
      <a href="Spear.htm">Spear of Destiny</a>
      <a href="PCTools.htm">Tools</a>
      <a href="PCEmu.htm">Emulators</a>
      <a href="Cheats.htm">Cheats</a>
      <a href="FileSpecs.htm">Versions</a>
      <a href="AlphaWolf.htm">The ALPHA File</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Macintosh</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="MacPlay.htm">MacPlay</a>
      <a href="Greg.htm">4th Encounter</a>
      <a href="MacTools.htm">Tools</a>
      <a href="MacEmu.htm">Emulators</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Wiki</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D">Wolfenstein 3D (Wikipedia)</a>
      <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear_of_Destiny_%28video_game%29">Spear of Destiny (Wikipedia)</a>
      <a href="http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D">Wolfenstein 3D (Wolfenstein Wiki)</a>
      <a href="http://wolfenstein.wikia.com/wiki/Spear_of_Destiny">Spear of Destiny (Wolfenstein Wiki)</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="SNES.htm">Super Nintendo (SNES)</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="Jag.htm">Atari Jaguar</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="3DO.htm">3DO</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="AppleIIgs.htm">Apple IIgs</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="Acorn.htm">Acorn Archimedes</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="Gameboy.htm">Gameboy Advance</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="PS3.htm">Playstation 3</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="XB360.htm">XBox 360</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="iPhone.htm">iPhone/IPod Touch</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="Symbian.htm">Symbian</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="TI83.htm">TI-83 Series</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="TI84.htm">TI-84 Series</button></div>
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" href="Maemo.htm">Maemo</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. Consider this the answer to the question I asked first.

Comment: @WayneCa Glad to hear that. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your mentioned problem of combining Buttons with Links is the actual problem. The main issue is the entire organization you started with. As already commented by someone else, why adding a button with a link in the first place? Completely unnecessary.
The right approach is not to sue a button but to use a Div-Box as a child of a link. That way you can style the Div-Box as you like and it will work as a button.
The right setup should be:

```css
.button {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  color: #103872;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font: bold 11px verdana;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href=index.html>
  <div class="button">Wolf3DMall</div></a>
<a href=Wolf.htm>
  <div class="button">Original PC</div></a>
<a href=index.html>
  <div class="button">Macintosh</div></a>
```

Also note: If you want to link within your own webspace, don't use the entire weblink which needs to be run through the DNS. It's faster, easier and resource-saving to link the path. If you need to go to a folder below inside the file hierarchy use:

> ../

Comment: At least this post gets closer to answering me. Why do I want the button to act as a link? Because it doesn't do it on it's own, and the way the site looks and functions is what I'm after. The entire organization is based on the idea that most of them will be droplists, and the few that aren't would be links to specific pages. This is an old page I recovered from webarchive, and I'm revamping it. I haven't dealt with the URL text yet, as I know they aren't right. I already know that I don't have to use the entire URL if I'm linking to a page on the site. Continued in next comment.

Comment: Also, I just uploaded the page so people here could look at it. Until now it has been offline. Floating the "button" left as you show will break the way the buttons across the top of the page looks, won't it? All I'm trying to do is keep the same look and feel to the link buttons as the droplist buttons have. If your method will accomplish that, then it's all I'm looking for there. but my main issue is still the space between the buttons. Any clues on how to accomplish that?

Comment: you dont need a button for that. A button is needed if you need to cause an event for JS as example. If you just want a "button" to be displayed, you should use a Div-Box. The drop downlist can be done with either hover or a click on that div-box-button. If you give me time, I will provide a code snipet for you to use.

Comment: float: left; will cause the div-box (buttons) to be displayed next to each other instead of below each other. of course the conent of the div-box can be added with child div boxes liek your hover did so that you have a drop down menu on hover.

Answer (score 1):

As [Juan Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes) said, there are not reason to use both tags. If you want to make `a` tag look like a button, there are two ways to do that, using styles or using javascript to simulate href (not recommended).

```js
function Redirect(){
  window.open('index.html','_blank');
}
```

```css
.aButton {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="aButton" href="index.html">Action</a>
<button onclick="Redirect()">Action</button>
```

Comment: This is what I was after. I only used both tags because that's what I knew and that's what worked. I came here to find out what better solutions there are. Thank you for giving me an answer.

Comment: Great @WayneCa, That's why StackOverFlow exists. Anyways, there are something called best practices. When you put a button inside a link tag and vice versa, you are commiting a bad practice, not because that gonna make your code fail, but because there is a function for each tag. `a` tag function is redirect somewhere and `button` tag function is execute a script. That's why the rest of people are so offset. Hope this help you in future.